# Replace input button text using jquery

Tags: jquery

I've been trying to figure out how to achieve this but havn't had any success.

Would appreciate some help.

I have an `input[type="submit"]`.

It's base value is always `"Next > some more text"`.

I wan't to add an `<em>` around the part `"Next >"` so that I would end up with
 `"<em>Next ></em> some more text"`.

Any ideas?

Comment: I'm not the down-voter, but I can't find any difference between the actual and expected.

Comment: After edit I see a difference but I don't see what's this text of the input. The value ?

Comment: Use a button instead of an input.

Comment: OP, you asked 127 questions (not counting the deleted ones) and you still need other users to do the basic formatting without which your question isn't even readable ?

Comment: @axrwkr I want to style the first part of the text differently - a different font.

Comment: @Musa - I can't its an asp.net button

Comment: @axrwkr - The problem with doing that is that lots of other things would break - its a default button in a panel and needs to inherit a specific interface

Answer (score 2):

You could just use:

```
input[type=submit] {
    font-style: italic;
}
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/Vvj4x/).

Though unfortunately this would italicize the *whole* of the element's text, rather than a specific portion.

An `input` element can't contain any other HTML, so it'd be impossible to wrap the `value` with an `em` element.

If you used a `button` element, though, you could use:

```
<button>
    <em>Next ></em> some more text
</button>
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/Vvj4x/1).

Comment: Thanks David - its not the answer I wanted to hear but its the right answer.

Answer (score 0):

Add an id to the button then:

```
$("#btnId").attr('value', 'New Text Goes here');
```